# Firebase Transaction Using PushID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am confused by the following behavior when making a firebase transaction. Any help would be much appreciated.

Problem:
I can create a transaction using the following, however, if I try to pass the pushID from the "pid" variable to the transaction reference, it breaks.  Can someone explain why this doesn't work, and what would be the correct way to implement?

```
upvote() {
const data = {};
var pid = firebase.database().ref('infos/').push();
var postId = pid.key;
console.log(postId);

firebase.database().ref('infos/' + postId +'/vote').transaction(function(value) {
  if (value) {
    value++;
  }
 return value;
});

}
```

Now, If I simply hard code a pushID into the "postId" variable, it works:

```
var postId = '-LNDP-7eKMxxUHqeRNWN';
```

Also In the first block the console logs the correct pushID, but does not create a transaction.

What am I missing?

thanks..

Edit:  I think using push() actually tries to push a new id to the variable that doesn't jive with the transaction..  Maybe?

Comment: When you say "it breaks" - what exactly do you mean happens?

Comment: nothing happens.  I don't get any errors or anything, the transaction just doest go through? I guess?

Comment: add some error checking.... maybe  use .catch and pass an onComplete function in to the push

Comment: 10-4, thanks, I'll add some in there and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your code works when you use a predetermined push ID, I am assuming the problem is a result of the transaction being called before the push ID is returned.

Try the following:

```
firebase.database().ref('infos/').push().then(pushed => {

firebase.database().ref('infos/' + pushed.key +'/vote').transaction(function(value) {
if (value) {
value++;
}
return value;
});

});
```